Different number of posts in regular loop and CPT category page
I have a few custom post types with custom categories – and i also use the regular posts page for news. At the moment i can only change the number of posts through Settings > Reading > Number of posts – but I would need to have different number of of posts on the CPT category pages. I tried something like this in functions.php:
/* Set limit of category pages to 99 */ 

function num_posts_archive_project_ie($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_archive('expert_db') && $query->is_main_query()) {
            $query->set('posts_per_page', 99);
   }
    return $query;
}

But to no success…:/
Any pointers or suggestions appreciated.
Cheers! t

You're halfway there. All you're missing is the right hook:
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'num_posts_archive_project_ie' );

The pre_get_posts hook fires after the main WP_Query object is instantiated but before it's sent to the DB.

omg yes! thank you very much!!
